# Matrix succeeds equal to 0

Tags: matrices, boundary-value-problem

I'm trying a reproduce the result of a paper.
The paper contains a formula:

[image: argmax formula with succeed equal]

X is a matrix. And this matrix should be "succeed equal" to 0.

[image: succeed equal]

What does this mean for the formula and for argmax? What does this compare operator mean in general?

Comment: Where have you seen the strange naming "succeed equal" ? Where is the success behind that ? Why not "backward looking eye" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I had this naming from wolframalpha: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SucceedsEqual.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We usually write the curly comparison $\succeq$ for more general comparison operations.  For vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we would write $x \succeq 0$ to mean that $x_1 \ge 0, ..., x_n \ge 0$.  For matrices, we write $X \succeq 0$ to mean that $X$ is positive semi-definite.  That is, all of it's eigenvalues are greater than or equal to zero.  (In convex analysis we generalize further, it is common to define a general comparison operator $\succeq_K$ with respect to some cone $K$.)

The operation $\underset{X \succeq 0}{\text{argmax }} f(X)$ returns the matrix $Z$ such that $Z \succeq 0$ and $f(Z) \ge f(Y)$ for any other $Y \succeq 0$.  That is, we optimize $f$ over the space of positive semidefinite matrices.

Answer (score 4):

It usually means that $X$ is [positive semidefinite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix).